# Where is Newid(), Rand(), and Sysutcdatetime() new value per query vs. row behavior documented?

Tags: sql-server, update, insert

Within a single query, all current time functions like sysutcdatetime() return a single point in time that is re-used throughout the query for each instance (e.g. of  sysutcdatetime()) no matter how complex (afaik).

However NewId() and Rand() do not follow this behavior and diverge from each other as well and it does not seem to be documented.  How to describe?  Are there other functions?

**Union All Example:**

```
select newid() as NewId, rand() as Rand, sysutcdatetime() as Utc
union all
select newid(), rand(), sysutcdatetime()
union all
select newid(), rand(), sysutcdatetime()
```

[image]

**Select Field Example:**

```
select top 1000000 newid() as NewId, Rand() as Rand, sysutcdatetime() as Utc
  from sys.all_objects AS s1 
  cross join sys.all_objects AS s2
```

[image]

**Update Example:**

```
create table #t
(
    NewId uniqueidentifier,
    Rand decimal(18,8)
)

insert into #t
select null, null
 union all
select null, null
 union all
select null, null

update #t
   set NewId = newid(),
       Rand = rand();

select * from #t
```

[image]

Comment: See explanation in duplicate question: _The `GETDATE` and `SYSDATETIME` functions are indeed non-deterministic, but they are treated as [runtime constants](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/conor_cunningham_msft/archive/2010/04/23/conor-vs-runtime-constant-functions.aspx) for a particular query. Broadly, this means [the function's value is cached](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/conor/post/rand%28%29-and-other-runtime-constant-functions-redux.aspx) when query execution starts, and the result re-used for all references within the query._ and _This behaviour is by design, ..._ for the `NEWID` function.

Comment: What is not covered is that there is also difference between rand() and newid() as shown in the examples.